# Horizontal line content is overlapping with axes : Chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I am creating a chart using chart js, putting few threshold lines also in that. But the content/title for those line is overlapping with x-axis if its value is 0 or in negative.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgTIP.png)

Comment: Try to define the option `scales.y.suggestedMin` as described here:  https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/#axis-range-settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to define the option `scales.y.suggestedMin`. This is a [common option to all axes](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/#common-options-to-all-axes).

> suggestedMin: Adjustment used when calculating the minimum data value.

For further information, please consult [Axis Range Settings](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/#axis-range-settings) from Chart.js documentation.